# Strange renaming behavior in using swig to ocaml

Tags: c++, ocaml, swig

I observed strange renaming behavior when
I apply swig to ocaml codes, which I reproduced
on a swig official example code(https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Examples/ocaml/std_vector) here:

example.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <numeric>

double average(std::vector<int> v) {
    # instead of calculating the average,
    # throw an invalid_argument
    throw std::invalid_argument("test");
    return 0;
}
```

example.i (same as the one found in the above link)

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include stl.i
/* instantiate the required template specializations */
%template(IntVector)    std::vector<int>;
%template(DoubleVector) std::vector<double>;

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "example.h"
```

This brings:

```
➜  std_vector git:(master) ✗ make
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f ../../Makefile 
SRCDIR='' SRCS='' \
SWIG_LIB_DIR='../../../Lib' SWIGEXE='../../../swig' \
PROGFILE='runme.ml' TARGET='example' INTERFACE='example.i' \
ocaml_static_cpp
rm -rf swig.mli swig.ml swigp4.ml && env SWIG_LIB=../../../Lib  ../../../swig -ocaml -co swig.mli 2>/dev/null && env SWIG_LIB=../../../Lib  ../../../swig -ocaml -co swig.ml 2>/dev/null && env SWIG_LIB=../../../Lib  ../../../swig -ocaml -co swigp4.ml 2>/dev/null &&  ocamlc -c swig.mli &&  ocamlc -c swig.ml &&  ocamlc -I ` camlp4 -where` -pp "camlp4o pa_extend.cmo q_MLast.cmo" -c swigp4.ml
env SWIG_LIB=../../../Lib  ../../../swig -ocaml -c++  -o 
example_wrap.cxx example.i
cp example_wrap.cxx example_wrap.c
ocamlc -cc 'g++ -Wno-write-strings' -g -c -ccopt -g -ccopt "-xc++ " 
example_wrap.c
ocamlc -g -c example.mli
ocamlc -g -c example.ml
(some warnings)
false ||  ocamlc -g -ccopt -g -cclib -g -custom -o example swig.cmo 
example.cmo runme.cmo example_wrap.o   -cclib "" -cc 'g++ -Wno-write-strings'
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this 
behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "std::caml_invalid_argument::~caml_invalid_argument()", referenced from:
  average(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) in example_wrap.o
  "typeinfo for std::caml_invalid_argument", referenced from:
  average(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) in 
example_wrap.o
  "vtable for std::caml_invalid_argument", referenced from:
      average(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) in 
example_wrap.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual 
member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while building custom runtime system
make[1]: *** [ocaml_static_cpp] Error 2
```

The problem is that, if some name (invalid_argument) coincides with ones predefined in ocaml C interface with "caml_" prefix (caml_invalid_argument), it looks like all the occurences of the former is replaced by the latter in some where during compiling.
I observed the same issue with a different name (initialize and caml_initialize) and different environments (macOS Sierra with clang or g++ and ubuntu 14.10 and g++).
Is this a bug in swig or ocaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file named `caml/compatibility.h` that has definitions exactly like this:

```
. . .
#define failwith caml_failwith
#define invalid_argument caml_invalid_argument
. . .
```

Perhaps it is being included even though it shouldn't?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for pointing out. Actually commenting out the line for invalid_argument solved the problem. I think this should be reported as a bug to swig...